# How to prevent a partition from being mounted [by dolphin]?

Tags: mount, backup, automount

I have a partition taking a whole separate drive that I use for backups. I don't want it to be automounted at startup or mounted by anything I'm not aware of because else it would kill the purpose of being protected against (amongst other things) `rm -rf /`. Here's a piece of my fstab:

```
#Backups
UUID=... /mnt/backups  ext4 nouser,noauto,ro,suid,dev,exec,async 0 2
```

This works with command line `mount` actions but as a normal user if I click on the drive in Dolphin it still gets mounted although while respecting read only mode, which makes it less harmful.

How can I totally prevent dolphin from doing its thing on its own with my partitions? I'm on a really fresh Kubuntu 14.04.

Note: I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67860/how-to-prevent-a-partition-from-being-mounted), but the asker said in a comment that he ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create a udev rules to ignore that hard drive.

1. Check drive serial number, using Disks utility (GUI)

   [image: get drive serial number]

   or using CLI:

   ```
   udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/sdb
   ```
2. Write a rule files

   `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/90-hide-disks.rules`

   ```
   ATTRS{serial}=="0000000000", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
   ```

   Replace `0000000000` with real drive serial number
3. Reload/Trigger the new rules

   ```
   sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
   sudo udevadm trigger
   ```

**References:**

- [Hide Your Disks Or Partitions From Nautilus](http://www.worldofnubcraft.com/969/hide-your-disks-or-partitions-from-nautilus/) (Quiet old)
- [How to reload udev rules without reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/how-to-reload-udev-rules-without-reboot)
- [How to Write udev Rules for USB Devices](http://weininger.net/how-to-write-udev-rules-for-usb-devices.html)
- `man udevadm` & `udevadm -h`

Comment: Well there's already a gui option in dolphin to hide the drive, and I could work around by assigning a failing mounting point to prevent automounting altogether, but do you have any idea on why dolphin bypasses fstab and how to cleanly fix that?

Comment: Nice but this hides entire drive, not a particular partition within a drive. OTOH, it looks like it is possible to [hide a particular partition only](http://askubuntu.com/a/236323/363039).