# Prevent hidden (for Windows 8.1) FAT32 partitions from being mounted when not even referenced in fstab?

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab, automount, fat32

I have two FAT32 partitions on my internal HDD that keep being (auto?) mounted by a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 even though **there is no reference to them whatsoever in /etc/fstab**.

If they were listed in /etc/fstab, I would have simply commented them out.
But they are not listed there.
Something else mounts them and I don't know what it is.

I will never have any use for these partitions in the context of Ubuntu, so I would like to prevent accidental access to them by never mounting them on boot.

How do I accomplish that?

Note: I found 2 similar questions but they are different from my case:

1. This guy [has entries in /etc/fstab](https://askubuntu.com/q/67860/363039).
2. This guy [also has entries in fstab](https://askubuntu.com/q/487139/363039) (and I have no idea what dolphin is)

Comment: Dolphin is a file manager (like Nautilus, the default file manager). Have you tried adding entries to `fstab` and using the `noauto` option?

Comment: @muru Thank you. Your suggestion was right on target (see my comment below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an entry to /etc/fstab, and specify the noauto mount option.  Partitions without any entry are auto mounted on demand by the file manager and udisks.  The noauto option prevents it from being automatically mounted at boot time.

Comment: Thanks. [This](http://askubuntu.com/q/487139/363039) seems to work, as when I click one of those "Devices" (left pane of the file manager, below "Places"), I get an error message box saying `Unable to access "RCVRY_DRV"`. So, the goal of preventing it from being accessed has been achieved. It would be nice if I could get it to completely be removed from the file manager's left pane, i.e. not even being displayed (and clickable), just as I did with the launcher by right-clicking that drive's icon and selecting `Unlock from Launcher`. Any way I can accomplish that?

Comment: @BillTheApe apparently the devices are shown only if you mount them in certain known locations, like /media, or a folder in $HOME, so a quick workaround could be to mount them elsewhere.

Comment: @BillTheApe, that should also prevent it from showing in the gui at all.